# can't run flutter on terminals

Tags: flutter, dart, terminal

I installed flutter on my pc and followed all steps in the download page, then I tried run `flutter doctor` on command prompt, first time it worked correctly and then it didn't work any more.
whenever I try to run any `flutter` command, it just shows up another terminal page and instantly disappear again and starts a new line as nothing happened.
[here is an image describes what's happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOkdw.gif)

I tried these solutions :

- I checked the Paths of environment variables, and they're all correct
- I tried to run the terminal as administrator
- I tried other terminals

but nothing worked.